# Searching for a Spanish word list for statistical analysis

Tags: computational-linguistics, resource-request, spanish, frequency, analysis

I need a Spanish word list, as simple as that.

The more complete it is, the better, it should contain as many words as to be a statistically relevant sample.

It can be in any format: XML, MS Excel, .txt. It doesn't need to be in any specific order.

I want to import it into a database, and make some statistical analysis about letter and syllable frequency and in what combinations do they appear, where in the word, etc.

Comment: What's pretty broad? I'm asking specifically for a words list, is that so offending and does it lower so much the quality of the site? Can you give an advice of how to ask this correctly so I get no censorship? @Alenanno would like to point me to the parts in http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq that this question is not abiding, so I can fix it, please?
Or you think this question is of no use and should be outright deleted?

Comment: First of all, keep your tone down and be respectful. I've clearly stated that the question was closed temporarily (closing **is** a temporary state, well that depends on you), but if you keep using this attitude, I'm not going to help you. This is no censorship. If it was censorship your question would be deleted and you suspended but luckily, I'm impartial in my judgement. I think you could try to include in your question: **(1)** what you tried searching in Google before asking (concrete examples) and **(2)** what kind of analysis you're willing to do.

Comment: Ahh, forget it.

Comment: You could get this question reopened if you showed a little more interest.

Comment: Do you just need the words themselves or do you also require definitions? Part of speech? Noun gender? etc? Do you want word forms (including plurals, conjugated verbs etc) or lemmas only (aka dictionary/citation forms)?

Comment: @Petruza If you include what I asked in my comment and also what hippietrails says in his comment, I'll see if I can reopen it. It's up to you now. I asked you to write what you searched because you've been too vague. I have no problem searching something for you, but we're not a searching service. I want to know that you *tried* at least and I'd like you to show it.

Comment: This question was originally asked on spanish.SE. I'd like to cross reference the two by linking: **[I need a Spanish word list for statistical analysis (as complete as possible)](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/i-need-a-spanish-word-list-for-statistical-analysis-as-complete-as-possible)**

Comment: @Petruza: I've been battling to get this question reopened. With quite some effort I have found a list with 354,227 definitions, of which 240,475 are unique forms. It includes proper nouns, inflected forms, prefixes, suffixes, abbreviations, initializations, and symbols among other things which you may or may not want. It is not 100% clean data. These are the kinds of extra details the site moderators would like you to specify to make this a great question. Please try to address these points so the mods will reopen your question. I am not a mod and can't open it on my own...

Comment: Yes, hippietrail has showed some interest in reopen it and I have no intention of ignoring it (we had a talk in chat). So @Petruza, if you make sure you address the points hippietrail asked and the ones I asked, I think it could get reopened and you'll get your answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks to both, when I have time I'll add those points to the question.